# Bigquery Job - Connexion closed

Tags: google-bigquery

I used bg command line for insert data in table and sometimes(1 or 2%) I has an error

> BigQuery error in load operation: Could not connect with BigQuery
>   server due to: error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host')

If I re-execute the command after, the job run successfully.

I didn't use Cloud Storage and Bucket but I'am already in Google network with a Compute Engine Server

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are encountering a high level of connection errors with your use of the `bq` command line client.

Connection errors occur when a server between your client and the BigQuery service terminates the connection. BigQuery itself always returns JSON payloads. If the `bq` client receives a non-JSON response, then it displays the error message "Could not connect with BigQuery server due to:" error messages. (The last part of the error message contains whatever some intermediate server encountered.)

Figuring out why you are seeing about 1% of your operations fail with connection errors may be difficult.

Perhaps your Google Compute Engine instances are running in regions that BigQuery doesn't have a presence? Right now BigQuery has a presence in Europe and in the United States. If you aren't running instances near those locations, then long distance network connections may be contributing to the problem. Try using a region in the US to see if you have better connectivity.

If you are in a region where BigQuery is, then consider opening a support request.  https://cloud.google.com/support/

As a work-around, you may be able to automate retrying BigQuery operations.

One caveat: the `bq` command line client does not retry operations on HTTP connection errors. In some cases this could result in duplicate work (for example, inserting a load job that allows the server to provide the job_id). In other cases this would conflate the error code "already exists" with success, which some use cases may want to distinguish.

If your use case is safe to retry, then your scripts could retry failing `bq` operations safely. You may want to write a custom client to do just the operations you need and do them in a safe-to-retry way. For example. bq.py uses bigquery_client.py to do it's work, and that programmatic layer has more functionality like the ability to "ignore_existing" on table.insert operations. While bq.py will fail to "mk" a table that already exists, bigquery_client.py's CreateTable can "succeed" even if the table already exists. This would simplify retry.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer,

Compute Engine & BigQuery data was store in same region, Europe for the both.

We will process re-execution when we catch error but it's strange that i have lost http connexion in Google Network.

In parallel, we open a support request